# Getting AspNetUsers to join to custom tables

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-identity, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to authorize a specific user to see only his own company-data. I have created a custom field in ApplicationUser called `CompanyId` and created a CompanyController (With the help of Erik Funkenbusch) as follows:

```
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Company
    public ActionResult Index()

{
        var companies = from c in db.Companies
                        join u in db.AspNetUsers
                        on c.CompanyID equals u.Company.Id
                        where u.UserName = User.Identity.Name
                        select c;
        return View(companies);
    }
```

However:`db.AspNetUsers` returns an *'does not contain a definition in ApplicationDbContext'*-error in VS2017. What am I overlooking? My context is (still) very standard and looks as followss:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think you can only have one datacontext per query but here you're doing a join on multiple contexts.

Comment: Where is that  db.AspNetUsers coming from?
 Isn't that property called 'Users'? See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151757(v=vs.108).aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext`6.Users

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the Property which contains the Users on an `IdentityDbContext<T>` is called `Users` and not `AspNetUsers`. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt151757(v=vs.108).aspx#P:Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext%606.Users)

So you should try this:

```
   var companies = from c in db.Companies
                        join u in db.Users
                        on c.CompanyID equals u.Company.Id
                        where u.UserName == User.Identity.Name
                        select c;
```

(Spot the part with `db.Users` instead of `db.AspNetUsers`)

Comment: I tried that. I Changed AspNetUsers to Users, but then I get a 'type' error of `where u.UserName = User.Identity.Name`: `cannot convert implicitly type 'string' to 'bool'.

Comment: Should I change the Where condition to: `where u.UserName == User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: Och, I see, you had a '=' there, instead of '=='. I fixed it in my  code snippet!

Comment: Change the Equalsign to double-equal